# SQL - Add calculated column to table MOD (%) Function

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

How can I add a calculated column to my table that will perform a MOD 10 calculation to the numbers that I have in column named "Value".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If your DBMS doesn't support adding calculated columns this is usually usually done in a View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need  just the result you can simply add  the calculated column to your select

```
SELECT *,  MOD(value, 10) your_new_col
from your_table
```

if you need  store this data  you should alter you table for add the column

```
alter your_table add  your_new_col (int)   /* assiming you work only with integer remaind */
```

then you can use update for store your result

```
 update  your_table 
 set your_new_col =  MOD(value, 10)
```